# How can I make the cursor blinking when calling focus() in the ondrop event?

Tags: javascript, html

In our app the user can drag and drop an element after which an input field gets focused. This works not exactly how I imagined it. The focusing works, however the input field shows a cursor (text caret) which is not blinking. If I click in the input field with the mouse it blinks. How can I fix this so after that the cursor in the input field blinks when focusing it from the drop event.

I created this small JSFiddle to demonstrate what's the problem. Just drag the text paragraph into the bordered div and see the cursor is not blinking.
https://jsfiddle.net/hxaty7vj/

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  ev.preventDefault();
  focusInputElement();
}

function focusInputElement() {
  document.getElementById('inputEl').focus();
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <br>
  <p id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">This is a draggable paragraph. Drag this element into the rectangle.</p>
  <input id="inputEl" />
  <button onclick="focusInputElement()">focus</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox calling `.focus()` on the input already works as you'd expect it, you'll see a blinking cursor. You might use a trick and add a CSS animation to the element as replacement of the browser-specific blinking and replace the animation with the "real" cursor blink when the element receives the focus:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  ev.preventDefault();
  focusInputElement();
}

function focusInputElement() {  
  document.getElementById('inputEl').classList.add('focused');
}

function removeBlink() {
  document.getElementById('inputEl').classList.remove('focused');
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}


input:focus {
  background-image:none;
}
input.focused {
  animation: blink-empty 1.5s infinite;
  background-image:/*linear-gradient(black,black)*/ linear-gradient(black,black);
  background-position: 1px  center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:1px 1.2em;
}
@keyframes blink-empty {
  10%, 90%{background-size:1px 1.2em;}
  30%, 70% {background-size: 0 1.2em;}
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<p id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">This is a draggable paragraph. Drag this element into the rectangle.</p>
<input id="inputEl" onfocus="removeBlink()" />
<button onclick="focusInputElement()">focus</button>
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot :)